# Как сделать поля ACF мультиязычными с помощью polylang?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Пишут, что `polylang` совместим с `acf`, но при добавлении поля `acf` нигде нет флажков или выбора языка.
У меня много полей, но теперь встал вопрос о мультиязычности. Все записи и страницы можно создать на нужных языках, но при добавлении поля `acf` нет такой возможности.

Answer (score 1):

В `functions.php` добавьте:

```
add_filter('pll_get_post_types', 'fixwp_add_acf_pll', 10, 2);
function fixwp_add_acf_pll( $post_types, $is_settings ) {
    $post_types[] = 'acf';
    return $post_types;
}
```

> В настройках Polylang в разделе Synchronization не должно быть галочки на  Custom fields